# iptables 1.4.12 invert and --u32

Tags: linux, iptables

This line in a script:

```
iptables -A jk2_ddos -m u32 ! --u32 "0x1c=0xffffffff" -j ACCEPT
```

will result in this error:

```
iptables v1.4.12: u32: option "--u32" cannot be inverted.
```

This seems not to work in iptables 1.4.12. In older versions it worked. I need something that does the same. The problem is i'am a tatal noob.

Does this line the same or is it nonsense?

```
iptables -A jk2_ddos -m u32 --u32 "0x1c=0xffffffff" -j REJECT
```

Thanks for your help

Edit:
This is the complete script.

```
# create chain

iptables -N jk2_ddos

# accept real client/player traffic
iptables -A jk2_ddos -m u32 ! --u32 "0x1c=0xffffffff" -j ACCEPT

# match "getstatus" queries and remember their address
iptables -A jk2_ddos -m u32 --u32 "0x20=0x67657473&&0x24=0x74617475&&0x25&0xff=0x73" -m recent --name getstatus --set

# drop packet if "hits" per "seconds" is reached
#
# NOTE: if you run multiple servers on a single host, you will need to higher these limits
# as otherwise you will block regular server queries, like Spider or QConnect
# e.g. they will query all of your servers within a second to update the list
iptables -A jk2_ddos -m recent --update --name getstatus --hitcount 10 --seconds 3 -j DROP

# accept otherwise
iptables -A jk2_ddos -j ACCEPT

# finally insert the chain as the top most input filter

# single server
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 28070 -j jk2_ddos
```

Comment: As it depends on the rest of your rules, the effect of this one rule doesn't match the original one with '!'.

Comment: But what does match it?